# Jquery ReEnable disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

For file upload, I've used a WordPress plugin.  
 
Here I want to control the maximum number of file upload. I'm able to disable the upload plugin when user upload the max number file.  
But after disabling the upload button, when the user delete a file and want to upload a new file he can't. How do I reEnable the disbale upload button? I've disabled the upload button, count with the total number of input class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var limit = 3;
    jQuery('.qbutton').on('click', function() {
        if (jQuery(".mfcf7-zl-multifile-name").length == limit) {
            jQuery(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
    jQuery('.mfcf7_zl_delete_file').on('click', function() {
        if (jQuery(".mfcf7-zl-multifile-name").length < limit) {
            jQuery('.qbutton').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

**update:** Event listener not work for dynamically create class **.mfcf7_zl_delete_file** 
After removing attach file click event not trigged.

Comment: .mfcf7_zl_delete_file is this class exist on page?

Comment: after adding a file this class will be visible. ( remove button with .mfcf7_zl_delete_file class name )

Comment: `disabled` should be prop and the usage should be `.prop('disabled', true)` and `.prop('disabled', false)` at least for jQuery > 1.6

Comment: nothing work at all.

Comment: By the way I also noticed that I can select multiple files on each click, i.e., open file dialog select 5 files and they are all selected. I'm not aware of this plugin you are using so I really can't comment on how it is being handled.

Comment: yah. I've also noticed that. Now I've to customize this plugin or need to buy a premium one :(

Comment: Plugin name is Multiple file upload for contact from 7

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to update your condition:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mfcf7_zl_delete_file', function() {
    // do the following stuff after deleting the file
    if (jQuery(".mfcf7-zl-multifile-name").length < limit) {
        jQuery('.qbutton').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't work. The target class didn't exist when document was loaded

Comment: yes.. but the click event will only be called when the class will exist on page...

Comment: Event listener will not be attached to dynamically created elements

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr, `on` will definitely attach the event listener to dynamically created elements.

Comment: @RashedulAlam, try my solution.

Comment: No it won't. Give it a try

Comment: @MuhammadZaib WordPress problem is a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your on click event is not getting triggered. Also need to re-check the condition.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'mfcf7_zl_delete_file', function(){ 
     if (jQuery(".mfcf7-zl-multifile-name").length < limit) {
            jQuery('.qbutton').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
});
```

Comment: **1.** traversing through entire document may not be the best idea unless all other parents in the tree were dynamically inserted. **2.** your code will not do anything because there is no element tag `mfcf7_zl_delete_file`, it should be `.mfcf7_zl_delete_file`. **3.** `disabled` is a `property` so `.prop('disabled', true/false)` should be used.

Comment: tried with every possible combination. Unfortunately nothing working.

Answer (score 0):

Since the target element doesn't exist on the page when the `document` is ready no event is attached to the elements that are created after selecting files for upload. Use delgation like

```
// $('container element').on('trigger name', 'dynamic target', function(e) {
    // do something
// });

jQuery('.mfcf7_zl_multifilecontainer').on('click', '.mfcf7_zl_delete_file', function(e) {
    if (jQuery(".mfcf7-zl-multifile-name").length >= limit) {
        jQuery('.qbutton').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

This will capture clicks on any `.mfcf7_zl_delete_file` that were added to `.mfcf7_zl_multifilecontainer` after the page was loaded.

By the way, notice that I used `.prop()` instead of working with `attr()`, see my comment on your question for details.

**EDIT:** Appears like wordpress adds elements dynamically. I have not much knowledge of wordpress. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var limit = 3;
        jQuery(document).on('change', '.mfcf7_zl_multifilecontainer', function() {
        if(jQuery('body').find(".mfcf7-zl-multifile-name").length >= limit) {
            jQuery('body').find('.qbutton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            jQuery('body').find('.qbutton').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

You can use an element (must be in the DOM path to `body` from your `.qbutton`) that you know for sure exists on page load instead of `body` in above code

Comment: not work again, I can add many file as i want :( thanks for your effort. Is it possible to handle this problem another way?  Such as count total number of file input filed or tolat number of file attached in input field.